# what is the difference b/w [1:] and lines[1:] in python?

Tags: python, dictionary, list-comprehension

Please explain to me the lines commented below :

```
def readfile(filename):
    lines = [line for line in file(filename)]
    cols = lines[0].strip().split('\t')[1:] #why [1:] here? what is it doing?
    rows = [] #whats the difference between rows = [] and rows = {}
    data=[]
    for line in lines[1:]: #what lines[1:] is doing?
        p=line.strip().split('\t')
        rows.append(p[0])
        #why we used float below if my file contains only integer numbers?
        data.append([float(x) for x in p[1:]])    
    return rows,cols,data
```

Comment: I would suggest looking at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/509211/understanding-pythons-slice-notation

Comment: `lines[1:]` will generate a sub list (a slice) of your `lines` list which begins from `index 1`. And you should know that lists in python begins from `index 0`

Comment: `rows = []` assigns to `rows` an empty list, while `rows = {}` assigns an empty dictionary. `lines[1:]` create a sublist starting from the second element of `lines`.

Comment: There are four different questions here, making this eligible for close as "too broad" if it *weren't* already a duplicate. Please see the guidance at https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic -- each SO question should be about one *specific* programming question that hasn't already been asked on the site.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`lines = [line for line in file(filename)]` will store each line from your data file into an array of strings, note that your data is separated by `\t` and each line ends with `\n` as all `for line in file` do.

Calling `lines[0].strip().split('\t')[1:]` means: from list of strings `lines` get first line (which I assume contains information about your data and not the actual data) `strip()` will remove the `\n` at the end, `split('\t')` will separate the information into a list where then you store `[1:]` (2nd to last elements) inside `cols`.

`rows = []` is creating an list to store information about your data row-wise just like `cols` is a list storing information column-wise.

Since we already parsed information in the first line `lines[0]` you want to process the rest so you loop over `lines[1:]`, before `[1:]` was used to go over the information in the first line and now to go over the remaining lines.

`p=line.strip().split('\t')` as before will strip your line of `\n` and split it on `\t` to store all your row info and data. `p[0]` I assume is your row-wise info of data and stored in `rows` list while the remainder is the actual data (in your case integers) stored in `data` which is an array  (list of lists of floats).

Even though your data is all in integers, `for line in file` will read it as a `string`. `float()` is used to be able to store the data as something you can use for mathematical operations later if you so need.

In the end if your file looks like this:

> Something name1 name2 name3 ...
>
> condition1 data1.1 data1.2 data1.3 ...
>
> condition2 data2.1 data2.2 data2.3 ...
>
> condition3 data3.1 data3.2 data3.3 ...

your output:

```
cols = ['name1', 'name2', 'name3', ...]
rows = ['condition1', 'condition2', 'condition3', ...]
data = [[data1.1, data1.2, data1.3, ...], [data2.1, data2.2, data2.3, ...], [data3.1, data3.2, data3.3, ...], ...]
```

Comment: Welcome to the site, and thank you for putting in the effort to build a comprehensive answer! That said, sometimes it's worth trying to get a more specific and unique question first -- a question about a single person's very specific code is likely only to be helpful to them, whereas a question about a single, more general problem will be helpful to everyone with that same issue. See "Answer Well-Asked Questions" in [How to Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer), and [How to handle “Explain how this ${code dump} works” questions](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/253894).

Comment: @CharlesDuffy thank you for your clarification. If this needs to be taken down let me know. I would link him the duplicates but everyone seems to send him links to only his first question about `[1:]` however in his post he asks 3 separate questions and no one tackled all 3. One approach would be to link him 3 references or more but truthfully I started with a simple answer and then kept editing into this long and elaborate answer.

Comment: No need to delete the answer -- it *is* clearly likely to be helpful to the OP. The "3 separate questions" thing is part of why the question is problematic -- but since you already put in the effort to build a good answer, we certainly wouldn't want to waste the time you spent.